# Obter texto de um elemento

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer uma validação básica em javascript puro.

Funciona da seguinte forma;
Tenho um `<h1>` onde é informado o perfil de usuário e preciso verificar o texto, conforme exemplo:

```
<h1 class="perfil-usuario">SISTEMA<h1>
```

E também tenho a condição:

```
 <script>

  var perfilSistema = document.querySelector(".perfil-sistema");

  if (perfilSistema  == 'SISTEMA' ) {
    window.location = "index.html";
  }
 </script>
```

Porém não está direcionando o usuário para a index quando ele recebe SISTEMA. Grato a quem ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente tem um erro no seu código, deve-se fechar a tag h1 assim: `</h1>`

```js
  var perfilSistema = document.getElementById("psistema");
  var text = perfilSistema.innerHTML;
  alert(text);
  
  if (text  == 'SISTEMA' ) {
   alert('estou dentro do if, vou redirecionar'); 
   window.location = "index.html";
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="perfil-usuario" id='psistema'>SISTEMA</h1>
```

**Explicação do código:**

isso serve para pegar o html de dentro do h1:

```
var text = perfilSistema.innerHTML;
```

e isso foi usado para pegar o elemento com o `id pSistema`

```
var perfilSistema = document.getElementById("psistema");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cole essas linhas em seu código e teste

Com Javascrip puro

```
  var cel = document.querySelector('.perfil-usuario').textContent; 
 if(cel == "SISTEMA"){
 alert("USER ENCONTRADO");
 window.open('http://www.google.com.br', '_self');
 //ou use  window.location = 'https://www.google.com.br' 
 }
 if(cel!="SISTEMA"){
 alert("USER NÃO ENCONTRADO");

 }
```

Com jJquery

```
var cel = $('.perfil-usuario').text(); 
     if(cel == "SISTEMA"){
     alert("USER ENCONTRADO");
     open('http://www.google.com.br', '_self');
     }
     if(cel!="SISTEMA"){
     alert("USER NÃO ENCONTRADO");

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Há dois problemas no seu código. O primeiro é que a consulta por essa classe irá retornar `null` visto que está buscando por `.perfil-sistema` quando o nome da classe no seu html é `.perfil-usuario`.

Além disso, você está comparando um objeto com uma string. Você deve comparar o "conteúdo" (nesse caso, o "texto") do elemento com [`Node#textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) ou [`Element#innerHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
var perfilSistema = document.querySelector(".perfil-usuario");

if (perfilSistema.textContent == 'SISTEMA') {
  window.location = "index.html";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="perfil-usuario">SISTEMA<h1>
```

Comment: Até deu certo @Renan,  mas no de classe não tem padrão obrigatório não. Você está meio enganado em relação a isso

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz não falei que é obrigatório, falei que sua consulta está errada.

Comment: Minha consulta?

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz `<h1 class="perfil-usuario">...<h1>` `document.querySelector(".perfil-sistema")`.

Comment: Agora que entendi.. É que foi só um exemplo, igual estava escrito aí na pergunta. Exemplos não são reais. Onde estou programando está certo

Comment: @Renan provavelmente por `SISTEMA<h1>` estar fechado incorretamente, deveria ser `</h1>`, o `textContent` deve estar talvez trazendo algo a mais, até espaços ou quebra de linhas.

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz Sobre o nome das classes conforme a pergunta apresentada, deve conter o código real do problema, para evitar que as respostas sejam levadas sobre problemas irreais.